# What is the advantage of using an Dynamic object over creating a class of that object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop

I would like to preface that I have not used Dynamic Objects very often, and only recently came across this problem. I have a specific scenario that I will explain *below*, but I was wondering what exactly were the advantages of implementing a dynamic object compared to creating a class for that object.

I have a method that takes a dynamic object as a parameter. For the sake of length I will not post much code just enough to get the point across:

```
public static Tax GetEmployeeTax(string Id, Employee employee, dynamic inputObject)
{
var temp = new Employee();
//use the dynamic object properties
return temp;
}
```

In this case, `inputObject` will have properties that help identify the employee taxes without directly being related to the employee class. Primarily I have given the `inputObject` the following properties:

```
dynamic dynamicEmployeeTax = new ExpandoObject();
dynamicEmployeeTax.FederalTaxInfo = "Some information";
dynamicEmployeeTax.StateTaxInfo = "Some other information";
```

Are there any advantages to making this it's own class versus using a dynamic object? Are there any benefits one way or the other?

Comment: Usually, you would opt for `dynamic` because you *need* to. Any reason why you cannot create a type for `inputObject`?

Comment: Well if you create a class for it then you'll get strong typing and compile time vs run time errors.

Comment: Agreed with @haim770, If you are consuming objects from some external source where you need to be able to accept different objects with some shared property that don't implement an interface or participate in some inheritance relationship and can't be changed, then you use `dynamic` as your last resort, not as your first choice. (alternatively, if you are just being too lazy to make a class - but ultimately that will probably come back and bite you).

Comment: @haim770 My instinct was to create a class, but for the purposes of this method, the business logic dictates that it must be a dynamic object. Personally it makes more sense to make it an object, but the reasoning behind this was based on simplicity. I posted to see if there were other benefits/drawbacks.

Comment: @rocat, If "the reasoning behind this was based on simplicity", a strongly-typed object is *much* simpler. Especially for the developers who are going to work with this method (and for the CLR as well, but that usually shouldn't bother you).

Comment: @haim770 I believe this is correct. I will see what I can do in the next few days, I will have to look at the code more closely. Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: All these wonderful comments and no answer? :)

Comment: On our dev team, if you use dynamic you have to have a *very* good reason to use it and be ready to explain why. Based on the comments above, we have very rarely run across a case where it was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why you want to create a class:

- Strong typing leverages the compiler to ensure correctness.
- Every class that encapsulates data is like a *contract*. You can imagine how's used by examining the class.
- You force the guy after you to read *how* it works. It is simpler to read class properties and image its utility.
- It is a sign a bad planning and engineering. You are creating blobs of data instead of structured data sets that solve a specific problem. Think mud pits versus Lego blocks.

The list goes on ad infinitum. I think the consensus here is to avoid it. There are extreme rare cases where this is useful. For most, stick to contracts and coding to abstractions not implementation details.